# Facebook authentication not working for nitrous.io meteor app (node.js)

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I have a meteor app running in a node.js machine on nitrous.io and the facebook authentication is not working.  I created a new app in facebook, added Website as platform, set the App domain to machinename.usw1.nitrousbox.com and the Website's Site URL to http://machinename.usw1.nitrousbox.com (machinename is made up, but I have my own site there) and then I used the public & secret key to set the fb auth in running meteor app.  This is all similar to how I've setup apps before, yet when I try to login to this nitrous.io app using fb, I get this from facebook:

```
    Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of
    the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the
    Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the
    App's domains.
```

I've tried all different kinds of settings.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the port? http://machinename.usw1.nitrousbox.com:3000

Comment: Yes, I did on both Site URL and App Domain and visit the exact same URL with port number via browser and logging in will get the same response... very strange.  I even tried resetting the meteor database, deleting the FB app, and redoing everything and it still cannot authenticate via FB.
Could it be that nitrous.io "preview" URLs resolve to a different domain or something?

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't think so. Did you try running the app on localhost and changing the app settings on facebook to localhost and logging in? If that does not work, that means we need to look elsewhere, if it does work, than that may be a nitrous.io problem which you can ask their support about.

Comment: Okay, I was out of the country for a few weeks.  So, I still cannot login using the built-in FB authentication of meteor on Nitrous.io.  This is a deal killer and will cancel my nitrous.io account unfortunately as I like it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this.

**Option 1:**

Meteor looks for a ROOT_URL environment variable to determine the url the app is running, which is `http://localhost:3000/` by default. You can keep the setting as is, but you will need to utilize the following credentials within your facebook app configuration:

site_url: `http://localhost:3000/`

**Option 2**:

If you want to utilize your preview URL then you will want to set the `site_url` to it within your facebook app configuration:

site_url: `http://machinename.usw1-2.nitrousbox.com`

The next step will be to start up Meteor with the following command:

```
$ ROOT_URL=http://machinename.usw1-2.nitrousbox.com meteor
```

Alternatively you can follow the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl) to change your root URL.

Comment: Thanks gman.  Regarding the first option, I can set site_url to http://localhost:3000/ but I cannot set App Domain to localhost.  Leaving it blank doesn't work.  Setting it to something nitrousbox.com gives a warning in FB when used with localhost in the site_url.  Ideas?

Comment: Would the second option work for you instead? I wasn't aware that fb doesn't allow localhost in the site URL. Try using `http://machinename.usw1-2.nitrousbox.com` for the site URL, replacing `machinename.usw1-2` with your actual box name and region listed within the preview URI on the boxes page.